# Find unknown exponent in Python with very large numbers

Tags: python, modulo, exponent

I am attempting to find `d` in Python, such that

```
(2 ** d) mod n = s2
```

Where `n =`

```
132177882185373774813945506243321607011510930684897434818595314234725602493934515403833460241072842788085178405842019124354553719616350676051289956113618487539608319422698056216887276531560386229271076862408823338669795520077783060068491144890490733649000321192437210365603856143989888494731654785043992278251
```

and `s2 =`

```
18269259493999292542402899855086766469838750310113238685472900147571691729574239379292239589580462883199555239659513821547589498977376834615709314449943085101697266417531578751311966354219681199183298006299399765358783274424349074040973733214578342738572625956971005052398172213596798751992841512724116639637
```

I am not looking for the solution, but for a reasonably fast way to do this. I've tried using `pow` and plugging in different values, but this is slow and never gets the solution. How can I find `d`?

Comment: Is that `2 ** (d mod n)` or `(2 ** d) mod n`?

Comment: The latter. Sorry, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Have you factorized n?  If n is the product of two large primes, a fast solution might represent a breakthrough in defeating http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm) (i.e., it is unlikely to exist).  If n has a large number of small factors, you should be able to break down the problem into easier-solved smaller problems.

Comment: I have not factorized `n`, and would expect this to be very hard since this is in fact an RSA problem, although I didn't mention that because it's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Well then, you should already know that the answer is that there is no reasonably fast way to do this. If you're looking for the least unreasonably slow way, you need to follow the state of the art in number theory, or at least read the Wikipedia pages on discrete logarithms and integer factorization.

Comment: I'm still learning, and I expected this to be somehow doable since the message is known and only the private key is not. However, the solution to the problem is out of the scope of this question, and so I'll try to solve that myself.

Comment: If it were doable, RSA would be crackable. That's not proof that it isn't doable, but it is proof that no one has figured out a way to do it yet (or, if they have, they're keeping it secret within the walls of the NSA or whatever).

Comment: "I expected this to be somehow doable since the message is known and only the private key is not." The private key is called "private" for a reason...

Comment: I realize that what I said doesn't make sense, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no known algorithm that can solve your problem. It's called [discrete logarithm problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), and some cryptosystems depend on its complexity (You can't find its solution fast unless you know factorization of n)

Comment: Ok, I will try to find a different solution. Thanks.

Comment: As requested: The solution was to realize that the product of the two example messages provided equals the third message (of which a signature had to be found). Multiplying the two example signatures yielded the signature of the third message.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the second answer to [Is it possible to get RSA private key knowing public key and set of "original data=>encrypted data" entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659477/is-it-possible-to-get-rsa-private-key-knowing-public-key-and-set-of-original-da).  A known-plaintext attack is no easier than known-ciphertext.

Answer (score 1):

The only known discrete logarithm solvers are built around knowing the factors. If you don't have the factors, you need to generate them.

The best reasonable-time algorithm for this is [Shor's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm). The problem is that you need a quantum computer with enough qubits, and nobody's built one large enough for your sample data yet. And it looks like it'll be quite a few years before anyone does; currently people are still excited about factoring numbers like 15 and 21.

If you want to use classical computing, the best known algorithms are nowhere near "reasonably fast". I believe someone recently showed that the Bonn results on 2^1039-1 should be reproducible in under 4 months with modern PCs. Another 5 years, and maybe it'll be down to a month.

It shouldn't surprise you that there are no known reasonable fast algorithms, because if there were, most private key encryption would be crackable and therefore worthless. It would be major news if someone gave you the answer you're looking for. (Is there an SO question for "Is P=NP?")